# Getting lot of crashes in Youtube Player API

Tags: java, android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I have implemented youtube player api in android app.

I get the following crash frequently while playing the video:

```
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void iqe.a(boolean)' on a null object reference
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at ioy.onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(SourceFile:115)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2561)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2199)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2419)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1744)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2771)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2380)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9529)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4230)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4096)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3787)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3844)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3661)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3642)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5857)
08-03 11:18:25.289 15393 15393 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInpu
```

The problem is that in order to find root cause of crash i need a line number in my code but the crash log in only Google Code.

I have tried to google about the crash in this method :

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void iqe.a(boolean)' on a null
>   object reference

However, this crash happens sometimes with method `isu.a(boolean)` instead of `iqe.a(boolean)`.

The Google and StackOverflow does not have any content / information about this crash or method.

I have tried to search for this method in my entire project but this does not result in any result.

Since the crash log does not have any line from my project i feel it very difficult to analyse what is the problem.

**When crash occurs:**

1. Play video, new Activity opens. > Press Back Button.
2. Repeat Step 1 10-20 times.

Comment: It seems the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/q/45172972/6305235 did you found any solution?

Comment: @DavidMiguel Yes the crash logs are same, however the use case is different. I will post the solution if I find one. The problem still persists.

Comment: created an issue https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/issues/22