# NullPointerException in onFilterTouchEventForSecurity with YouTubeBaseActivity

Tags: android, android-youtube-api, youtubeplayer

Am using an Activity which extended from YouTubeBaseActivity and YouTubePlayerView to play Videos from Youtube. sometimes app crashes with below exception.

```
    "STACK_TRACE": "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual 
            method 'void mcr.b(boolean)' on a null object reference 
     mbe.onFilterTouchEventForSecurity(SourceFile:32)
            android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2193) 
            android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671) 
            android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)
    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)
    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
        android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)
    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671) android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301) 
    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent
    (ViewGroup.java:2671)android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:23
    01)android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2671)
    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2301)
    com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:447)com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent
    (PhoneWindow.java:1871)android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3213) com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:409)at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10232) 
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4862)android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4723) 
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4255) android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4308)
     android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4401)android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4282) android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4458) android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4255) android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4308)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4274)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4282)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4255)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6682)android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6656)android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6617) android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6809)android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:356)android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

How to resolve this issue? did't my research but didn't find any effective way.

also referred : [Getting NullPointerException at onFilterTouchEventForSecurity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45172972/getting-nullpointerexception-at-onfiltertoucheventforsecurity)

[Getting lot of crashes in Youtube Player API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857554/getting-lot-of-crashes-in-youtube-player-api)

Comment: simply `void mcr.b(boolean)` is null. check it.

Comment: its came from youtube api, i can't do null check there

Comment: created an issue https://github.com/youtube/yt-android-player/issues/22